# How can i put a flash animation in the header of a movable type 4.2 site?

Tags: css, movabletype

Im creating a new site  i a i want a flash animation in the header of my page, im using Movable Type 4.2.

The problem is i don't know how can i do that, and which file i need edit, or if i can do all the job in the dfashboard of movable type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can certainly be done through the MT dashboard. You'd need to modify the current templates to include what you need.

In the MT dashboard, go to *Design* > *Templates*. That'll be the general area you'd need to examine and, if you want to fully customise your blog, it's the area you need to become very familiar with.

Start by looking at the *Banner Header* template module.